# Shed Moisture problem

Tags: ventilation

I keep getting moisture in the bottom part of my 12x12 shed. Mostly on the plywood floor but also on some of lower walls and bench about 3ft high and then seems to be fine above that.
I have 8x8in gable vents on both end and going to increase size to 12x12. I have read that adding vent at lower corners close to floor could help with this problem. I was wondering on any suggestions of what would be a good size and I was going to put two on both sides, front and back.
thanks
Dean

Comment: Where is the damp coming from?  is it coming from the ground? from the sky? or from the air?

Comment: Have you been using a combustion heater in there? Combustion creates carbon dioxide and water vapor.

Comment: I have no idea where it’s coming from and no heat in shed.

Comment: I am looking for suggestions on what size of vents to put down by floor on side walls to help with cross ventilation.